# Flutter. don't stop play mp3 file from link when i leave page

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I parsing html page on flutter using Html class. On some html pages there players which open links with mp3 file. And when i leave these page, music don't stop playing. How stop it.

```
    Html(
                data: news.dbf_str_content,
                style: {
                  "body": Style(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  ),
                  "p": Style(
                    fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                  ),
                },
                onLinkTap: (url, _, __, ___) {
                  if (url.contains("fonds/detail")) {
                    String isin = url.replaceAll(
                        "https://www.example.com", "");

                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailPage(isin: isin)));
                  } else {
                    launchUrl(url);
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: We have no idea what you are doing, therefor we can't help.

Comment: i build page reading html fileб using flutter_html

Comment: By leave page do you mean you do Navigator.pop or Navigator.push to another screen?

Comment: Yes. when i do Navigator.pop , audio keeps playing.